# How long does it take for the results to appear in the Google DATASET search?

Tags: dataset, google-search, google-knowledge-graph

We have setup a dataset markup for one of our sites and provided a sitemap for it.

Do you know how long it takes for the results to appear in the *Google DATASET search*?

The results appear in the regular Google search but as of yet it doesn't appear in the *Google DATASET search*. The Google Search console also shows as all URLs having  been indexed.

Also the markup is generated using AJAX, does that have any impact? (We can see the generated markup using the `Google Structured data testing tool`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our experience it took about 4 weeks; but not sure if that's the standard time

Comment: Yes, mine just got approved a couple of days back.